# Google Calendar Sync replacement?

Tags: google-calendar

I would like to sync my work outlook calendar with a google calendar.  But I read that the Google Calendar Sync program is being retired in Jan 2013.  What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, if you sign up for Google Sync before January 30, you will still be able to use it.  Only new sign-ups are ending.  (Though if you uninstall, you can't reinstall...)

There are extensions available for Outlook that allow you to sync with CalDav calendars like Google Calendar.  [SyncDroid](http://www.syncdroid.net) has a list of a bunch of different ones -- they recommend [CompanionLink](http://www.companionlink.com/google/outlook/).  [Sync2](http://www.sync2.com) is also pretty popular.

You can also use outlook.com, Microsoft's own online calendar; I think it's free, but you'd have to migrate all your data over.

Comment: "Just so you know, if you sign up for Google Sync before January 30, you will still be able to use it." - Not any more, it will shut down for everyone in August 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Try any third-party tool. I personally use [Sync2](http://www.sync2.com/) to sync my inbox, calendar and contacts between work desktop and my laptop. Useful piece of software.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include more detail on what the service has to offer, rather than just linking to it.

Answer (score 1):

[gSyncit](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit3/) works reliably.

*From linked page:*

> gSyncit is a Microsoft Outlook add-in that allows for the
>   synchronization of Outlook calendars, contacts, notes, and tasks with
>   your Google account. In addition, gSyncit also supports
>   synchronization between Outlook and Toodledo, Pocket Informant Online,
>   Evernote, Dropbox, Simplenote and Nozbe.
>
> Sync your iOS iPhone/iPad with Outlook using gSyncit and your Google
>   account. Some sync functions require additional apps for your device.
>     Sync your Android device with Outlook using gSyncit and your Google
>   account. Some sync functions require additional apps for your device.
>     WINDOWS 8 & OUTLOOK 2013 / OFFICE 365 (DESKTOP CLIENT) SUPPORTED

Comment: I've edited your answer to include a little more detail. Typically link only answers are not acceptable.

Comment: @Fogest - Thanks. It's funny though - I am pretty sure I never clicked the button to save my answer. I decided to bail out while typing so I hit the back button and I suspect the site was trying to be smart and saved my input anyway. I actually hadn't intended to leave the answer!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a good free alternative yet, but Google's own "Google Apps for Business" provides this feature and more for much less than other alternatives popping up - only $5 per month verses $15 a month and up I've seen advertised elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found this today :
https://outlookgooglesync.codeplex.com/releases/view/105332
It's free, open source, and looks non intrusive. FTW!

Comment: Can you expand on that? How will this solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Now that the Google Calendar Sync has stopped working I found a replacement Outlook4Gmail. Although it isn’t free it works great, actually better than Google's own product did.